# Add to cart form return parameter help

Tags: cartthrob

So I have a product listing page with each product displaying having an add to cart button.

This is done like so:

```
{exp:cartthrob:add_to_cart_form entry_id="{entry_id}"}
    <input type="submit" value="Add to basket">
{/exp:cartthrob:add_to_cart_form}
```

All very well and good for a regular listing page. However this page also has a search feature, where search parameters are GET variables in the URL. Not having a return url strips the search so that is not the way forward.

So I decided to use the [Mo' Variables {current_url} tag](https://github.com/rsanchez/mo_variables#current-page-url) to push in the full URL. The problem I'm having now is when I have a search query like this:

```
http://emc.dev/publications?keywords=media&category:formats=9
```

The problem here is that when CartThrob comes back it gives the message `Disallowed Key Characters.` and the url is now:

```
http://emc.dev/publications?keywords=media&category;:formats=9
```

Why is CartThrob adding a semi-colon before my colon?

Thanks in advance

Edit: I have already checked in the hidden fields in the add_to_cart_form and the return url is set properly:

```
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="/publications?keyword=media&amp;category:format=9">
```

Comment: Hey Joe, did you get anywhere with this issue? We're seeing exactly the same behaviour :-/

Comment: @AndrewArmitage I did actually, I'll answer my own question below this - plum forgot I had this up here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a support call with CartThob I have this fixed. Turns out its actually a CodeIgniter issue (kinda). The request is basically passing through CI's XSS filter, which is picking this up as a possible XSS threat and escaping it.

The way I got around it was making a small addition to the `system/expressionengine/third_party/cartthrob/libraries/Form_builder.php` file.

Around line 714 you should see the code block

```
if ( ! $this->return)
{
    $this->return = ($this->EE->input->get_post('return')) ? $this->EE->input->get_post('return', TRUE) : $this->EE->uri->uri_string();
}
```

Which, with the addition, becomes

```
if ( ! $this->return)
{
    $this->return = ($this->EE->input->get_post('return')) ? $this->EE->input->get_post('return', TRUE) : $this->EE->uri->uri_string();
    $this->return = str_replace("category;:","category:",$this->return);
}
```

Obviously replacing "category" with whatever word(s) you are using.

Hope this sorts it for you too!

Comment: Thanks Joe, thats worked perfectly - much appreciated you taking the time to add an answer :-)